# How performance heavy is String concatenation?

Tags: java, android, performance, micro-optimization

Following situation: I have a lot of log statements which should be only exectuted when in Debug mode.

I have two options on how to implement this:

### A

```
public void log(String message){
    if(debug) doLog(message);
}
```

and a lot of statements like this:

```
log(something.toString() + "somelogmessage");
```

### B

```
public void log(message){
    doLog(message);
}
```

and a lot of statements like this:

```
if(debug) log(something.toString() + "somelogmessage");
```

While A is better to read and produces less code, B avoids the String concatenation if debug is false.

Is it worth to write this extra boilerplate code for the performance gain?
Or are these anyways equal (e.g. because of compiler optimization)?

Comment: A good JIT compiler will probably optimize both source options into similar machine code, but IDK how aggressive the JVM is on android.  This is one of the cases where JIT compilation can beat ahead-of-time compilers, by generating a version of the code that checks for `debug` being false once, and totally omits everything that is unused in that case.  (I think this is the sort of thing real JIT compilers like OpenJDK/SunJDK's "server" VM for x86-64 do in practice, but I haven't looked at the native asm generated.)

Comment: Anyway, it *is* possible to look at the native machine-code / asm that JIT-compilers generate.  I forget how; I don't usually use Java, but IIRC there's a SO Q&A with ways to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned (and you've acknowledged with your tag), this is a micro-optimization and likely to be irrelevant in the vast majority of cases. But if you're looking to avoid concatenation without making a mess of your code, you can add an overload that accepts two parameters:

```
public void log(Object prefix, String message){
    if(debug) doLog(prefix.toString() + message);
}
```

and then call

```
log(something, "somelogmessage");
```

If your messages can be made of multiple values, you can use varargs instead:

```
public void log(String... values){
    if(debug) doLog(String.join("", values));
}
```

though the performance benefit is even more questionable in this case.

Comment: I probably should've mentioned that not all log calls use exactly one Object followed by a String. The combination and number of Strings and Objects vary between calls.

Comment: see my question on Victors answer.

Comment: @F43nd1r, concatenation involves a bit more than just array allocation, but as I said, it's definitely a questionable performance benefit. If there's one thing more problematic than micro-optimization, it's trying to compare different optimizations without rigorous testing.

Comment: @F43nd1r Have a look at [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html) as it does a lot of optimizations. Concerning your case, you can define methods with up to let's say three arguments (`Object`s rather than `String`s) and one varargs method. Primitive boxing and varargs array allocations are still cheaper than string concatenation (moreover calling `Whatever.toString()` may be much more costly).

Answer (score 3):

I mean technically, option B will be slightly faster because it doesn't factor in a conditional everywhere, but for something as small as this, I would definitely recommend going with option A.  The amount of overhead is so small that it's negligible, and not worth the added code for the conditionals you'd have to throw in all over the place.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge about compiler optimizations which might be applied here? Would performance increase if `debug` is final?

Comment: If you were using a final variable initialized outside of a constructor (like `BuildConfig.DEBUG`), the compiler should optimize it out.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a for loop or some real heavy code I'd use the debug check.

If it's just a couple of concats I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could improve performance and avoid superfluous concatenations using, for example, [PrintStream format method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) in your log implementation after the checking debug level.

You could also take a look to [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html). It has methods like `debug(String format, Object... objs)` that prevent concatenation. It also have `isDebugEnabled()` thats is very useful when you have to do complex login.

A couple of concatenations are not going to be a big problem, but you should consider add new methods to your log API or use SLF4J with some implementation (e.g. logback)

Comment: using varargs produces overhead too: an array has to be allocated. Why should an object array allocation be faster than a char array allocation?

Comment: varargs are subject to further optimisations, there is an important performance difference between JRE6 and JRE7 (I do not know about 8). Anyway, SLF4J has its own ways to optimise such calls (e.g. `void debug(String format, Object arg1, Object arg2)`)

Comment: @F43nd1r Both allocations take about the same time (it's just a pointer bump), but the numbers should make it clear: The concatenated string is usually longer, so more garbage gets produced. More importantly, copying the chars takes longer as copying the references (as from every reference you get a couple of chars).